# Problema con success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

estoy con un problema con un comando AJAX por algún motivo no consigo que pase por el SUCCESS y no soy capaz de encontrar el error, de repente alguno podría pasarme la mano, explico mi problema.

**el boton btn-remove**

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>mantenimiento/categorias/delete_funcion/<?php echo $categoria->id;?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-remove"><span class="fa fa-remove"></span></a>
```

**llama a la funcion AJAX**

```
var base_url= "<?php echo base_url();?>";
    $(".btn-remove").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var ruta = $(this).attr("href");
        //alert(ruta);
        $.ajax({
            url: ruta,
            type:"POST",
            success:function(resp){
                //http://localhost/ventas_ci/mantenimiento/productos
                window.location.href = base_url + resp;
            }
        });
```

**Que a su vez llama al controlador categorias con la funcion delete_funcion**

```
public function delete_funcion($id)
    {
        $data = array
        (
            'estado' => "0", 
        );
        $this->Categorias_models->update_model($id,$data);
        echo "mantenimiento/categorias";//retorna el controlador categorias para q pueda actualizarce la pagina
    }
```

**este esta enlazado con el modelo modelo_categorias en la funcion update model**

```
public function update_model($id,$data)
    {
        $this->db->where("id", $id);
        return $this->db->update("categorias", $data);
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la edición, justo miraba como hacerlo..

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. No se entiende bien tu pregunta ni la relación que tiene la llamada a Ajax con `delete_funcion`. ¿Qué es lo que no funciona? Empieza por probar si el código entra en la parte de Ajax, poniendo por ejemplo: `alert(ruta);`  debajo de la declaración de esa variable. Y explica con más claridad cómo tienes organizado el código, qué esperas que haga, qué hace actualmente, etc. La pregunta se puede corregir o mejorar pulsando donde dice `editar` en la parte inferior de la misma, al lado de `compartir`.

Comment: Este código es parte de un archivo php? `var base_url= "<?php echo base_url();?>";`

Comment: Podrías ver esta pregunta [how-to-get-the-jquery-ajax-error-response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637019/how-to-get-the-jquery-ajax-error-response-text) para aprender a mostrar los errores por consola o un alert. Esto te va a ayudar a saber que es lo que está pasando. Saludos!

Comment: @Juan base_url es una variable q cree para usar en el codigo ajax pero si forma parte de un php.

Comment: @Juan si, forma parte de un ajax q esta en el php en ese codigo guardo en la variable base_url la base_url pero del php era solo para no escribir y reescribir, xq se usa el llamado en otras circunstancias.

Comment: @FranIslas Gracias, voy a mirar la pregunta. parace muy interesante!!

Comment: Haz mirado en tu controlador que el metodo es correcto? es decir que es "POST" en vez de "GET"?

Comment: @JorgeBowen gracias x tu respuesta amigo, este proyecto lo estoy creando a partir de un tuto, en el mismo se utiliza el metodo POST, pero me podrias explicar la diferencia entre el post y el get? como veras soy un noob en el tema, gracias.

Comment: El metodo GET se utiliza mas para devolver en el navegador una respuesta, el metodo POST se utiliza mas para enviar datos al servidor, en ambos se pueden hacer pero el GET tiene mas limites por ejemplo al enviar una cadena larga de caracteres el GET tiene un cierto limite el POST no, de todas formas, estaria bien incluir tu archivo de rutas para ver que metodo es el que esta asociado a esa ruta en tu controlador.

Comment: var base_url= "<?php echo base_url();?>"; ("base_url() = localhost/ventas_ci")
resp = segun entiendo recibe lo q se envio atraves del echo en la funcion delete_funcion del controlador categorias 
Por lo que lo q se concatenaria en 
window.location.href seria localhost/ventas_ci/mantenimiento/categorias
eso seria para actualizar la pagina y ya no muestre el registro eliminado